# How to create a Python Object from a C++ Object using Boost.Python

Tags: c++, inheritance, python-2.7, boost-python

I have a C++ project that use a lot of classes. The main one is '`sso::Object`' (every classes are in the 'sso' namespace) and this class is derived into some other classes but one which is abstract: '`sso::Drawable`'.

This class has two pure virtual methods '`sso::Drawable::set_opacity`' and '`sso::Drawable::raw_draw`' and it is derived into other classes like '`sso::View`' which implement these two methods.

The whole project works fine when it is used in C++, but I would like to use it in Python too, so I created a Boost.Python module like that:

```cpp
class DrawableWrapper : public sso::Drawable , public wrapper<sso::Drawable> {
public:
    void set_opacity(byte opacity) { this->get_override("set_opacity")(opacity); }

    void raw_draw(const sso::Rect &rect,sso::Target &target,const sso::Position &position) const {
        this->get_override("raw_draw")(rect,target,position);
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(sso) {

    class_<DrawableWrapper,boost::noncopyable> ("Drawable",init<>())
        .add_property ("opacity",&sso::Drawable::get_opacity)
        // python_sso_getter & python_sso_setter_* are only used for an easier access to accessors
        .add_property ("position",python_sso_getter<sso::Drawable,sso::Position,&sso::Drawable::get_position>,python_sso_setter_1_const<sso::Drawable,sso::Position,&sso::Drawable::set_position>)
        .def("raw_draw",pure_virtual(&sso::Drawable::raw_draw))
   ;

    class_<sso::View,bases<sso::Drawable> >                 ("View",init<>())
        .def("insert",python_sso_setter_1<sso::View,sso::Drawable*,&sso::View::insert>)
        .def("remove",&sso::View::erase)
    ;

}
```

This code compile without errors but when I execute these lines in Python:

```
myview = sso.View()
print myview
```

I get this output:

> <sso.View object at 0x7f9d2681a4b0>

But my C++ debugger tell me that the variable 'v' (the python 'myview') is a '`sso::Object`' instance, not a '`sso::View`' one. `sso::View::View()` is called but the variable type is not a view and I don't know why. Do you have any idea about that ? Did you do something like that and found a way to make it work ?

I use Python2.7 and Boost.Python1.49 and gcc version 4.6.1

EDIT: I've made a mistake: `sso::Drawable` does not inherit from `sso::Object`, but `sso::View` does (=multiple inheritance).

Answer (score 1):

The output `<sso.View object at 0x7f9d2681a4b0>` from python is just python telling you what it thinks the object type is called, it has nothing to do with the actual type of object created at the C++ level.

As you've told boost python to expose the object as `sso.View` then that is what python will see it as.  If you were to change your code to expose `std::string` as `sso.View` then python would still report `<sso.View object at 0x7f9d2681a4b0>` after you've created it.

Similarly, if you were to change `"View"` in your C++ to `"BlahDeBlah"` then python would report the object as `<sso.BlahDeBlah object at 0x7f9d2681a4b0>` (of course you'd also have to create it via `sso.BlahDeBlah()`

That aside, I can't see anything wrong with the code you have posted.  Does `sso::View` inherit from `sso::Object`?  If that's the case, and you've witnessed `sso::view::View()` being called, then I think you might just be misinterpreting the debugger when it tells you the object is of type `sso::Object`.  Perhaps it has a pointer to the base class or something similar at the point you are debugging?

What happens when you call `myview.insert` or `myview.remove` from python?

EDIT:  I suspect (though I could be wrong) that you might not have RTTI turned on in your compiler, so `typeid()` is just returning the type that implemented the function you are in when you called `typeid()`.  That would certainly explain why you get `sso::View` when in `insert` but a different answer in other functions.

Anyway, I've been looking into the documentation a little bit more and I think your problem is actually that you've provided the ability to override the `raw_draw` method but you haven't actually overridden it with anything.

If you have a look at the decleration of the `pure_virtual` boost::python function [at the bottom of this file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/python/pure_virtual.hpp) you'll see a comment:

```
//
// Passed a pointer to member function, generates a def_visitor which
// creates a method that only dispatches to Python if the function has
// been overridden, either in C++ or in Python, raising a "pure
// virtual called" exception otherwise.
//
```

So what you're seeing is just expected behaviour.  If you provide an override for `raw_draw` in `sso::View` or a python class that inherits from it then you should no longer get this error.

Comment: `sso::View` inherit from `sso::Drawable` which inherit from `sso::Object`, so indirectly, yes, View inherit from Object (all the inheritances are public in this case).
myview.insert is already used in my script and works fine (the `sso::View::insert()` method is called). I think the problem is that sso::Drawable is abstract and Boost.Python don't know to make an object from a class inherited from an abstract one.

Comment: I used typeid().name() to get the object type: in the insert() method I got `N3sso4ViewE` (=`sso::View`) and in an other method where I make my tests, I got `N3sso6ObjectE` (=`sso::Object`)

Comment: This error make my program crash because the `sso::Object` class does not have the raw_draw method so I get an Abord signal with the message : "pure virtual method called"

Comment: @Wysiag I think I've figured out your problem, and I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I saw, thanks. I'll modify my code later to test that. There are something that I don't understand: my `sso::View` class override the raw_draw method and I don't have any problem using this class in my C++ programs. Do you think I need to redeclare this method in the Python definition ?

Comment: Since you're seeing the problems that you are, I would expect so.  I definitely think that seeing `sso::Object` in the debugger is just a red-herring anyway.

Comment: oops. I'd just read my classes declarations and it seems that `sso::Drawable` does not inherit from `sso::Object` at all. Sorry for that. So I realy don't understand why my View become an Object.